# Data for some bound fields not appearing on report

Tags: activereports

I'm creating a 'SectionReport' (Active Reports V.9), and am dragging bound fields from the 'Report Explorer' directly onto the report. I've written the SQL query, which executes and returns the correct results as expected.

However, only a small portion of the bound fields are displaying data from the table.

Again, when I execute this in the 'Query Designer', I see all data. When I save that exact query, only some of the data is populated on the report.

This process seems so straight forward and yet I seem to be missing something.

Please help and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So you're saying the data is returned but not showing up in some of the fields?   Have you checked the binding for each of those fields?

Can you step with the debugger and verify that in the detail_format even there is data in report.fields for those records that have missing values.

can you add debug statements that print each field value in the detail_format event.

based on what you described all I can offer is some diagnostics techniques.   If you'd like please send your report to our support team and we can properly inspect it and help you out  http://arhelp.grapecity.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the enduserdesigner sample or the pre-compiled exe that comes with the installer, can you please make sure that the PreviewPages to a larger number instead of 10.

You can change the value by follwing these steps.  in report exploer, double click the settings node.  go to gloabal settings tab and change the previewpages value.

If this is not the case, please attach the report.  There are no other settings that will cause this.